# Why is my counter not updated by "count == count + 1"?

Tags: python, loops, counter

```
 answers = []

   for syn in all_words :
      count = 0
      result = [syn, count]
      for Document in Corpus:
         for Word in Document:
            if syn == Word :
               count == count + 1
               
      answers.append(tuple(result))
```

i'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a given word from all_words in each document in a corpus. For some reason, the count is always 0.

Comment: Typo: `count == count + 1` should just be 1 `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using a comparison operator (`==`).
- What you want instead is an assignment operator (`=`).
- To make life a little easier, you can use the increment shortcut of `+=`.
- Example:

```
...
if syn == Word :
  count = count + 1
...

# Is Equivalent To:
...
if syn == Word :
  count += 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count == count + 1
```

You're using the wrong operator.

The double equal sign `==` is a *comparison* operator.  It tests if the two arguments are equal.

The single equal sign `=` is an *assignment* operator.

Use `=` instead of `==`.